# How to keep scrolling div at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this js that works great until I get to the bottom of the div, it then is relative and jumps back up to the top. I would like it to stay at the 2000px location instead of jumping back to the top as I continue to scroll down (we have a very large footer). Any ideas? I have looked through a lot of these, and I have been unable to get any codes to work that indicate they could do what I am trying to do.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 2000) {
            $('#scrollingDiv').css({ position: 'relative' });
        } else {
            $('#scrollingDiv').css({ position: 'fixed' });
            $("#scrollingDiv").css("top", Math.max(0, 170 - $(this).scrollTop()));
        }
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f85fmnzr)

Here is the general idea of it. The main difference is that our footer is very large (i was not able to add the footer without major editing) so I need it to stop at a point that is at the end of the image but also stay at the bottom of the image as I continue to scroll down to view the footer.

Comment: Any way you could throw this in a jsfiddle with your html so we can see it working and better understand what you need?

Comment: Please describe a little more background - what should this div do? Stay at the bottom of the screen until 2000px of scrolling, then...what? Stick to the page at its current position?

Comment: Okay give me a few minutes to get it in jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f85fmnzr/ Here is the general idea of it. The main difference is that our footer is very large (i was not able to add the footer without major editing) so I need it to stop at a point that is at the end of the image but also stay at the bottom of the image as I continue to scroll down to view the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. The way this code works is that the div will be fixed and scroll down (located at the top of the browser) until it hits 2000px. Then it switches to relative positioning and will stay at 1750px so you can continue to scroll down without the div coming with you. When you scroll back up, it will pick up the div and bring it back to the top with you.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 2000) {
            $('#scrollingDiv').css({ position: 'relative' });
            $('#scrollingDiv').css({ top: '1750px' });
        } else {
            $('#scrollingDiv').css({ position: 'fixed' });
            $("#scrollingDiv").css("top", Math.max(0, 170 - $(this).scrollTop()));
        }
    });
```